# Testing if a state is in final state

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Please excuse my language, I am new to the topic.

I am trying to classify/find a class of game that describes games such as chess, tic-tac-toe as a finite state machine.

For those games, final states are easy to determine and can be efficiently checked.

My question is:

1. is there a name for such class of games/programs?
2. is there a game/program such that there is no way to determine the final state?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem ?

Comment: [Combinatorial games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory).